# Fast object outlining algorithms? (computer vision, python)

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I am looking for a good algorithm or library for outlining grayscale objects which are set on a white background.  I am *not* detecting objects, I am just trying to trace their outline and set that trace on a separate image.

For now, I am only trying to do this with images that are already centered and set on a white background.  For example, the MNIST datasets.

I am also *not* looking for outline approximations.  I want the actual exact outline, or the best outline that can't be detected.  So if my object was, for example, a pizza with a tiny slice missing - then the outline would be a circle with a tiny slice missing.  As another example, if my object was a circular pizza crust with all the pizza missing from the middle, then the outline would be a single circle.  It would not outline both sides of the crust.  And for a final example, if the object was that same pizza crust but with a tiny bit of crust missing, then in this case the outline would in fact capture both edges of the crust, because the outline would slip inside the circle from where the crust was missing.

From google searches I am having trouble finding such an algorithm or library.  Can anyone help me?  Thank you.

Comment: you may be interested in opencv [`findcountours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0), see also [this tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html)

Comment: yeah I found that.  unfortunately, while really cool, it finds edges internal to the object outline.

edit:  actually scratch that,  I found a tutorial where they are using findcountours to do exactly this.

Comment: did you check the [`RetrievalModes`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71), in particular `RETR_EXTERNAL`?